# How do i save the login state in laravel if i'm using an api to login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I'm working on an ecommerce site which requires the user to sign up and login. This app was first built in android and the APIs and database already exist. I have to use these APIs to create a web version of the app. I decided to use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for consuming the APIs. But my challenge is, if the user log in and i send the request through the API and the login was successful, how do i save the login state in my web app.

Comment: By using cookies, your need to link them to the authenticated users session and handle gc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057302/setting-up-cookies-for-guzzle-cookiejar - if you use JWT you can hold state all the way through.

Comment: I would build this using angular or vue or whatever javascript framework you're familiar with instead of using PHP, the way you're doing it right now you cannot track users (All of your requests would be coming through the server instead of users) And since it's an e-commerce site that would be a big disadvantage